# upgrading a custom db to azure app services

Tags: azure-mobile-services, windows-10-universal, azure-web-app-service

I have an exixsting windows 8 app connected to an azure customdb, shared with a web app, using azure mobile services.
I would like to write a new version of the app for windows 10 using azure app services, but I don't find documentation about the changes using a custom existing db.
Where can I find it?

Comment: Are you using the Azure SQL Database for the existing windows app? I think you can follow the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-dotnet-simple/ to get the connection information and configure it for the new version of win10 app.

Comment: the problem isn't the connection itself. I wrote the first version of the backbone using the mobile services specs. I haven't found any specific documentation about writing custom backend using mobile app

Answer (score 1):

The changes to the database between Azure Mobile Services and Azure App Service are identical.  If you want a tutorial on how to use an existing table and project it into mobile apps, I wrote one here:  https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/11/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-19-asp-net-table-controllers/ - it's part of a sequence of posts, so you may have to go back a couple of posts to get to the start of the ASP.NET ones.

Comment: One update - there is a slight difference between AMS and AAS.  In AMS, the system columns are preceded by a double-underscore (i.e. things like __version, __updatedAt, __createdAt and __deleted)) - in AAS, they are not (so version, updatedAt, createdAt and deleted)